When sending email via SMTP - How to suppress "Connection Closed Gracefully" dialog
"Connection Closed Gracefully" dialog is shown when sending email (SMTP) if there is some condition that causes the network connection to close. The dialog always appears and I seem to be unable to suppress it.
Below is the code we use to send email and this works everywhere. We have identified a network issue that's closing the connection issue.
The issue I have is that I'd like to suppress the dialog and any underlying exception when this occurs, since it seems to interfere with processing that would normally follow the email request.
Is there a way to stop the dialog from appearing at all?
procedure SendEmail(Host, From, Recipients, Subject, Body, CC, BCC, ReplyTo: string;
                    Port: Integer; IsBodyHtml: Boolean);
const
  CHARSET_UTF8 = 'utf-8';
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage: TIdMessage;
  builder: TIdMessageBuilderHtml;         
begin
  IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  try
    builder := TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create;
    try
      // Set charsets.
      builder.PlainTextCharSet := CHARSET_UTF8;
      builder.HtmlCharSet := CHARSET_UTF8;

      // Populate the message body based on the HTML flag.
      if IsBodyHtml then
        builder.Html.Text := Body
      else
        builder.PlainText.Text := Body;   

      // Populate the message with the builder's data.
      builder.FillMessage(IdMessage);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(builder);
    end;

    // Set up email details.
    IdMessage.From.Address := From;
    IdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := Recipients;
    IdMessage.Subject := Subject;
    IdMessage.CCList.EMailAddresses := CC;
    IdMessage.BccList.EMailAddresses := BCC;
    IdMessage.ReplyTo.EMailAddresses := ReplyTo;

    // Create and configure SMTP client.
    IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    try
      IdSMTP.Host := Host;
      IdSMTP.Port := Port;
      IdSMTP.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;

      // Attempt to connect and send the message.
      try
        IdSMTP.Connect;
        IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      except
        on E: EIdConnClosedGracefully do
        begin
          // Suppress connection closed gracefully error dialog.
        end;
        on E: Exception do
          ShowMessage('SMTP Error: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    finally
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
      FreeAndNil(IdSMTP);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IdMessage);
  end;
end;


The error is raised as an exception. You are not catching the exception, so it escapes into the runtime, which then displays the dialog.
Simply catch the exception with a try..except block around the SMTP code.  Right now, you do have a try..except but only around the Connect() and Send() calls, but the Disconnect() call can raise too (as it sends a QUIT command to the server).
The Disconnect() call should not be in the same finally that frees the TIdSMTP object.
Try something more like this:
IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
try
  ...
  try
    IdSMTP.Connect;
    try
      IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
    finally
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  except
    on E: EIdConnClosedGracefully do
    begin
      // Suppress connection closed gracefully error dialog.
    end;
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('SMTP Error: ' + E.Message);
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(IdSMTP);
end;

